# What is the meaning of "contain the group"?

Tags: phrases

I come across the following `BBC` news:

> These gains have undercut the core pillar of the US strategy against IS. But airstrikes and limited ground operations by local forces can contain the group if not defeat it as yet.

How to understand "*contain the group*"? I have tried to google it, but get nothing.

Comment: Above and beyond googling, have you looked up the verb *contain* and the noun *group* in an English dictionary? If not, please do so, and update your question. If so: what did you find? What questions remain?

Comment: @DanBron: I don't know the `group` represents `IS`, as Avon has referred. So I thought "`contain the group`" is a slang originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Group in the sentence refers to IS (Islamic State).

To contain means to have or hold (someone or something) within.

It is often used in strategic language in that way. Containing the enemy is stopping them from growing; militarily, geographically, economically or in any other way.

Therefore, the airstrikes and limited ground operations by local forces can stop IS from conquering new territory, building up their arsenal, etc...

Comment: Yes, and if you de-acronymize the "IS" to "Islamic State" It may be even easier to demonstrate that confusing bit.